# How can I organize my domain names?

Tags: domain-registration

I have some domains registered with 1and1 and some with dreamhost and hosting on both companies but some point to hosting with dns.  It's all a mess!

Is it best to register your domains through a registration company and then just point them to  hosting company?

Any recommendations how I can clean this up?!

Comment: Can you explain some more about the exact situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosting company of your choice will not always be the best for keeping domains with. There are, however, advantages to having one chosen company for each of these services, mainly due to keeping everything clean and organized.

I use Media Temple as my hosting company of choice, mainly due to the freedom and ease of use but keep domains registered by a Polish company that has a neat management tools for domains. I then just park the domains on Media Temple by configuring them to work with MT's DNS servers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is best to keep domains registered with one company and then setup DNS and hosting as needed for each domain. It makes it a little easier to manage domain renewals in one place to make sure you don't lapse. Most of the time, the hosting company's DNS service is sufficient, but there might be reasons where you want to manage DNS separately. And of course, hosting is all over the place. One site might do fine on a shared grid server, another on managed hosting, another on a virtual private server with all kinds of customizations, and another might require a specialized host like heroku or wpengine.